# Why can't my program find the class Stack?

Tags: java, stack

For me and my partner's project, we are trying to build a program for a calculator in Java. Can you guys please tell me what is wrong?

```
public class InfixtoPostFixParens
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    //data fields
    /**The operator Stack */
    private Stack<Character> operatorStack;
    /** THe operator */
    private static final String OPERATORS = "+-*/";
    /** The precedence of the operators mathces the order in Operators */
    private static final int[] PRECENDENCE = {0,1,1,2,2,2};
    /** Postfix string */
    private StringBuilder postfix;

    private void processOperator(char op){
        if(operatorStack.empty() || op == '('){
            operatorStack.push(op);
        }else{
            //peek the operator stack
            //and let topOp be the top operator
            char topOp = operatorStack.peek();
            if(precedence(op) > precedence(topOp)){
                operatorStack.push(op);
            }else{
                //pop a;; stacked p[eratprs wotj equla or higher precedence than op
                while(!operatorStack.empty() && precedence(op) <= precedence(topOp)){
                    operatorStack.pop();
                    if(topOp == '('){
                        //matching ( popped - exit loop
                        break;
                    }
                    postfix.append(topOp);
                    postfix.append(' ');
                    if(!operatorStack.empty()){
                        //reset topOp
                        topOp = operatorStack.peek();
                    }
                }
                //assert operator is empty ot current operator precedence > top of stack operator precedence
                if(op != ')')
                {
                    operatorStack.push(op);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public String convert(String infix){
        operatorStack = new Stack<Character>();
        postfix = new Stringbuilder();

        try{
            //process each token in the infix epression
            String nextToken;
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(infix);
            while((nextToken = scan.findLine("[\\p{L}\\p{N}]+|[-+/\\*()]")) != null){
                    char firstChar = nextToken.charAt(0);
                    //is it an opperand
                    if(Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(firstChar)){
                        postfix.append(nextToken);
                        postfix(' ');
                    }// is it a operator
                    else if(isOperator(firstChar)){
                        processOperator(firstChar);
                    }else{
                        //throw new error
                    }
                }

                while(!operatorStack.empty()){
                    char op = operatorStack.pop();
                    if(op == '('){
                        //throw error
                    }
                    postfix.append(op);
                    postfix.append(' ');
                    return postfix.toString();
                }
        }catch(EmptyStackException ex){
            //throw error
        }
    }
}
```

When I compiled it, I get an error saying "It cannot find symbol- class Stack."

Comment: What are your imports?

Comment: I'd use "InfixToPostfixParens" for the name of the class. Regarding the question - add imports as others suggest.

Answer (score 3):

`Stack` is one of a massive number of classes that are available to be used in Java programs. However, the vast majority of Java programs don't need to use the vast majority of these classes, so it would be senseless (and, for all intents and purposes, impossible) for all of them to be included in every program. Instead, we store all these classes in [libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Class_Library), and each time you write one of your own, you `import` the specific classes it needs from those libraries.

You do so using `import` statements, which should be placed at the top of your class file, below the package declaration and above the declaration of the class:

```
package yourPackageName;

import java.util.Stack;
//other imports 

class yourClass { 
//constructor, code, etc... 
}
```

Note that the syntax for import statements is: `libraryName.libraryName.className` (where there can be any number of nested libraries separated by dots): `Stack` is a part of the `util` library, which is a part of the `java` library, hence:

`import java.util.Stack`.